# $(-x+2)^2=(x-2)^2$ this is true but why?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I came across this identity in an old textbook:

$$(-x+2)^2=(x-2)^2$$

My only problem is that it does not feel natural. It is hard for me to visualize why this is true. A simple explanation on how to think about this problem would be really nice. Thanks in regard.

Comment: $-x+2=-(x-2)$ and so the squares are equals.

Comment: Well, how do you feel about, say $(-5)^2= 5^2$ ?

Comment: @leonbloy the 2 also flipped from positive to negative so that got me confused.

Comment: $$(-1)^2=1...$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opposite numbers have the same square, for example:
$$4^2 = (-4)^2 = 16$$
This holds for any real number $a$, symbolically:
$$a^2 = (-a)^2$$
So it also holds for $x-2$; take $a=x-2$ in the formula above and you have:
$$(x-2)^2 = \bigl( -(x-2) \bigr)^2 = (2-x)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}(x-2)=(-1)(-x+2)\\(x-2)^2=(-1)^2(-x+2)^2\\(x-2)^2=(-x+2)^2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

When you square something, there is no matter with what sign you are taking it, for example: $n^2=(-n)^2$. It applies to every even number in the power $n^4=(-n)^4$ and so on... In our example, $n = x - 2$ and $-n = -2 + x$.